# Constraining d3 force layout graphs based on node degree

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I have a force layout with potentially a very large number of nodes, too large for the graph to render responsively. I was thinking that one way to improve the performance of the system was to prune the graph by eliminating nodes based on in- and out-degree when the number of nodes gets too large.

Recomputing the node and link lists is a bit of a nuisance because links are related to indexes in the node array, and so all the links would need to be re-built.

It seems more elegant to be able to mark individual nodes for exclusion (analogously to the way some nodes are `fixed`) and have the layout algorithm skip those nodes. This would allow me to dynamically select subsets of the graph to show, while preserving as much state for each node (e.g., position) as practical.

Has anyone implemented something like this?

**UPDATE**:

I tried to implement the filter suggestion, but ran into an interesting error. It appears that the `filter` method returns an object that does not implement `enter`:

```
qChart apply limit:2
NODES BEF: [Array[218], enter: function, exit: function, select: function, selectAll: function, attr: function…]
NODES AFT: [Array[210], select: function, selectAll: function, attr: function, classed: function, style: function…]
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'enter'
```

The following code is run to get from `BEF` to `AFT`:

```
nodeSubset = nodeSubset.filter(function(n) { return (n.sentCount() <= limit); });
```

**UPDATE 2**:

I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gene/umMML/) to isolate the problem. This example implements my interpretation of ChrisJamesC's answer. When I tried to implement his suggestion directly (putting the `filter` after the `data`), the subsequent call to `enter` failed because the object returned by `filter` did not have `enter` defined.

The goal is to make the layout select only those nodes that have `active == true`, so in this example, this means that node `b` should be excluded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `selection.filter()` option combined with the `node.weight` attribute.

What you would normally do is:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
```

Here you can do:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .filter(function(d){return d.weight>3})
    .enter();
```

You might also have to remove from drawing the links going to these nodes using the same method.

**EDIT** You should just filter the data you provide if you want to mark nodes as active directly in the data array (and do the same for links)

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(force.nodes().filter(function(d) { return d.active; }));

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(force.links().filter(function(d) { 
          var show =  d.source.active && d.target.active;
          if (show)
              console.log("kept", d);
          else
              console.log("excluded", d);
          return show;
      }) );
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisJamesC/umMML/2/)

If you want to do this by computing the weight of each node, I would still recommend you to do this before passing the nodes and links to the graph and mark nodes as active or not following a specific criteria, then filter the links according to active nodes. Otherwise you would have to load the whole force directed layout only to get the weight to then filter the data to re-load the force directed graph.

Comment: I tried to implement your suggestion, and ran into a problem, as shown in the edits to the question. Basically, the `filter()` method returns something that doesn't have `enter()` defined.

Comment: Sorry. Can you build a jsFiddle?

Comment: OK, that makes sense, but will that keep the force layout from touching the excluded data objects? Or will force still try to position them?

Comment: they will be in the force layout, so their position will be computed.

Comment: I guess that means I need to apply the filter at the force, rather than on the DOM level. I am trying to de-clutter the force layout to make it perform better.